# calls to cmd from powershell not parsing correctly?

Tags: powershell, curl, cmd

I am trying to run cURL.exe from powershell as part of a larger script to create various user accounts as new individuals are onboarded.
(I cannot use invoke-method or invoke-webrequest because the header parameter wont accept a string)

The issue is that I can run it from a cmd window perfectly but I cannot seem to make the same thing run from powershell:

```
curl.exe -H "Authorization: {\"apiKey\":\"ResetAPIKey,\"username\":\"admin\"}"  -d "username=someUserName&email=somebody@domain.com&firstName=Joe&lastName=Friday"  "http://URL:8080/v1/users/create"
```

This runs just fine from cmd but when attempting to run from powershell, I get errors like 'url not found' or 'That path/method is not supported'

Additional format attempts:

- encasing the whole thing in single quotes
- replacing each   **/"** (forward slash + double quote) with **`"** (backtick + double quote)
- adding all the arguments to a here-string variable
- variations of above

I would assume I can write it to a .bat file and then run that from powershell but I'd rather not be forced to do that if possible

Comment: Consider the [stop parsing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) parameter `curl.exe --% -H "Authorization: ...`

Comment: Matt,
That worked perfectly.  I never knew about that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Matt, 
actually the one issue with that, is that i wont be able to use variables inside of it to specify the username etc of new users.  It works well when items are statically set but wont be dynamic.

Comment: I threw up an answer that should cover that need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [stop parsing parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) is a good choice for this type of thing.

> The stop-parsing symbol (--%), introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0,
>       directs Windows PowerShell to refrain from interpreting input as 
>       Windows PowerShell commands or expressions.

In your case though you need something a little different as you want variables in the mix that need to be resolved.

I figured there would be a dupe for this. Most of those answer are about converting `curl.exe` to something like `Invoke-WebRequest` which is something you should look into. In this case, if you have dynamic content use the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) like this.

```
$arguments = "-H ""Authorization: {\""apiKey\"":\""ResetAPIKey,\""username\"":\""admin\""}""  -d ""username=someUserName&email=somebody@domain.com&firstName=Joe&lastName=Friday""  ""http://URL:8080/v1/users/create"""
&"curl.exe" $arguments
```

Noticed I doubled up the inner quotes on the string. If you look at the variable after it would display properly. Now you should be able to make changes.

Comment: Hey Matt, 
This ended up working with a little bit of modification.  I also used backticks instead of doublequotes .  
I wasnt able to use invoke-webrequest or invoke-restmethod because they only accept headers that are idicitionary or a hashtable but the rest api appears to only accept url encoded json strings

Answer (score 2):

Passing complex command line to native application from PowerShell can be tricky. PowerShell can add extra quotes in some cases. Although, rules for this are not that complex, but them are not well (if at all) documented, and also there is some substantial changes in that rules in v2-v4 vs v5. IMHO, using stop parsing operator `--%`, as [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt) offered, is the best approach, in case you targeting on v3+.

Stop parsing operator does not limit you to use literal strings only. You still can use variables with it. That operator expand environment variables in `CMD` syntax: `%VariableName%`. So you can assign required values to some environment variables and use them in command line:

```
$Env:Env_UserName='someUserName'
$Env:Env_Email='somebody@domain.com'
$Env:Env_FirstName='Joe'
$Env:Env_LastName='Friday'
curl.exe --% -H "Authorization: {\"apiKey\":\"ResetAPIKey,\"username\":\"admin\"}"  -d "username=%Env_UserName%&email=%Env_Email%&firstName=%Env_FirstName%&lastName=%Env_LastName%"  "http://URL:8080/v1/users/create"
```

Other variant will be to generate full arguments line, you want to pass to native application, and than pass it in single environment variable:

```
$Arguments=...
$Env:Env_Arguments=$Arguments
curl.exe --% %Env_Arguments%
```

Answer (score 1):

Matt's answer with the call operator looks like it should work, but if it's not there's a similar alternative I've had good luck with before. Instead of passing your arguments as a string, you can pass them as an array and PowerShell will handle them correctly. In your case, it'd look something like this:

```
$arguments = @("-H", 'Authorization: {\"apiKey\":\"ResetAPIKey,\"username\":\"admin\"}', "-d", '"username=someUserName&email=somebody@domain.com&firstName=Joe&lastName=Friday"', 'http://URL:8080/v1/users/create')

& "curl.exe" $arguments
```